# Creating digital elevation map using QGIS

Tags: dem, tandem-x

I am very new to QGIS and I want to create a digital elevation map a particular region.

Can you give me a step by step procedure to do this?

Answer (score 11):

There is lots of information about creating DEMs but you must be clear about what data you have.

1. [Creating a DEM from contours](http://linfiniti.com/2010/12/3d-visualisation-and-dem-creation-in-qgis-with-the-grass-plugin/)
2. [Creating a DEM from vector data](http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Creating_a_DEM_from_vector_data#tab=Content)
3. [Creating Maps from SRTM Data](http://www.google.com.tr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=create%20dem%20from%20srtm&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFYQFjAA&url=http://www.prosimco.com/atf/tutorial/images/creating_maps_from_srtm_data.pdf&ei=ZEvfT734HcuIhQe765SpCg&usg=AFQjCNFqEOCs08r-NH7BJx5_VUMsugCL8g&cad=rja)
4. [Inverse Distance Weighting (IDW) Interpolation using QGIS](http://www.gistutor.com/quantum-gis/20-intermediate-quantum-gis-tutorials/51-inverse-distance-weighting-idw-interpolation-using-qgis.html)
5. [A workflow for creating beautiful relief shaded dems using GDAL](http://linfiniti.com/2010/12/a-workflow-for-creating-beautiful-relief-shaded-dems-using-gdal/)

[image: dem]

Comment: The links posted by Aragon are mostly invalid

Comment: This was answered more than 10 years ago so it might make sense that they are no longer valid; I mean the links.

Answer (score 3):

A DEM either constitutes or requires a data input, it's not something the GIS can create itself.  QGIS needs some indication of where the ground is.  That data may be created via a ground survey effort, an aerial LIDAR scan, photogrammetric interpolation, or through a plane or satellite-based synthetic aperture radar.  There are workflows that may incorporate GIS software to modify these datasets, but we'd really need to know where the data is coming from to help there.

The two big semi-global DEMs out there are the Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM):

http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/elevation/item/45-srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v41

and the Advanced Spaceborne Thermal Emission and Reflection Radiometer (ASTER):

http://asterweb.jpl.nasa.gov/gdem.asp

There's also the upcoming TANDEM-X product:

http://www.dlr.de/hr/desktopdefault.aspx/tabid-2317/3669_read-5488/

These are relatively raw data products, with some holes and artifacts.  SRTM, at least, has been around quite a while now, and has been smoothed out and refined into national-scale production-ready data products by a number of organizations.  The National Elevation Dataset is the official US DEM:

http://ned.usgs.gov/