# Creating Digital Elevation Model (DEM) from Google Earth Image?

Tags: dem

I am very new to GIS and given the task to create DEM's of agricultural area. I have studied the advantages of DEM in agriculture now i just want to know how i should start to develop the DEM's ? How i can create the Digital Elevation Model (DEM) from Google Earth Images ??

Comment: you don't create dems from google earth.  you will need several imagery products to accomplish this. also you would need one of several software possibities

Comment: Kindly explain then how i should proceed...

Comment: you are not clear enough of the software you are capable of obtaining /using for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Duplicate question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27665/how-to-create-a-digital-elevation-map)

It is a very detailed process as you can see by this [usgs lesson](http://education.usgs.gov/lessons/dem.pdf).
You can follow it only if you have the software listed here.
Also DEM is a somewhat varied format that can have slightly different  headers, type values, etc.
Also there are several digital products used in 3d analysis that all have similar information.
DEM, DTM, TIN, NED, NLCD, LIDAR,
Reference other information [here](http://www.gsd.harvard.edu/gis/manual/dem/)

There are several other software available to duplicate this process.
I believe the osgeo4w would allow creation (not with exactly these steps).
To get some knowledge you could request demo software listed in the usgs lesson, and then after understanding the workflow perhaps find other software (e.g. grass, gdal [found in osgeo4w]).

just search google "create digital elevation model"